# What is the proper way to logout the user via class-based view using Django Token Authentication?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-login

I have my login view working perfectly, and I think the logout view should work properly as well, but everytime I click on the button to logout user, it gives error `AonymousUser object has not attribute 'auth_token'`.

My **`views.py`** is below:

```
class LoginAPIHTML(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'accounts/login.html'

    def get(self, request):        
        serializer = LoginSerializer()
        return Response({'serializer': serializer})

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response({'serializer': serializer})
        
        user = authenticate(request, username=request.data['email'], password=request.data['password'])
        
        if user:
            Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('user')

        else:
            return redirect('login')

class LogoutAPIHTML(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]

    def get(self, request):
        request.user.auth_token.delete()
        logout(request)
        return redirect('login')
```

and the template from where I click the logout button is below:

```
<body>
    <h1>Use Details</h1>
 
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">
        <input type="button" value="Logout"/>
    </a>
    {% else %}
    <h2>{{ message }}</h2>
    {% endif %}
</body>
```

and my `CustomEmailBackend` is in `authentication.py`, and defined as below:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class CustomEmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        return None
```

Error details are below:

```
AttributeError at /logout
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'auth_token'
```

```
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Users\Khubaib Khawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 55, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
Local vars
C:\Users\Khubaib Khawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 197, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
Local vars
C:\Users\Khubaib Khawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py, line 54, in wrapped_view
        return view_func(*args, **kwargs) …
Local vars
C:\Users\Khubaib Khawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py, line 84, in view
            return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) …
Local vars
C:\Users\Khubaib Khawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py, line 509, in dispatch
            response = self.handle_exception(exc) …
Local vars
C:\Users\Khubaib Khawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py, line 469, in handle_exception
            self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc) …
Local vars
C:\Users\Khubaib Khawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py, line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
        raise exc …
Local vars
C:\Users\Khubaib Khawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py, line 506, in dispatch
            response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs) …
Local vars
C:\Users\Khubaib Khawar\Downloads\Meistery\Round2\backend_dev_trial_ass_r2\accounts\views.py, line 221, in get
        request.user.auth_token.delete() …
Local vars
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (you don' t provide the implementation of `LoginSerializer`) that in your login view you don' t actually create an authentication token. Try this:

```py
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token


class LoginAPIHTML(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'accounts/login.html'

    def get(self, request):        
        serializer = LoginSerializer()
        return Response({'serializer': serializer})

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response({'serializer': serializer})
        
        user = authenticate(request, username=request.data['email'], password=request.data['password'])
        
        if user:
            Token.objects.create(user=user)  # Here
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('user')

        else:
            return redirect('login')
```

Comment: Hi @RedWheelbarrow I did as you said, I added the `Token.objects.create(user=user)` but it still giving the same error. I have updated the question and added more details of the error. PLease have a look.

Comment: @NehaAK The problem maybe is that your login view did not create the token, so try to force the logout, login and then test again (the new login method must be called to test it)

Comment: I just read somewhere that I need to have `permissions_classes = [IsAuthenticated]` and `authentication_classes = [YourAuthBackend]` in my `LogoutView`. I have imported `IsAuthenticated`, but I have a customer backend model in my `settings.py`, how do I import that in `views.py`?

Comment: @NehaAK `from project_name.settings import backend_name`

Comment: OK I added both of those and now I am getting this error `'CustomEmailBackend' object has no attribute 'authenticate_header'` @RedWheelbarrow

Comment: @NehaAK Try to remove `authentication_classes`, if you set your settings correctly it should work anyway

Comment: Well, I removed `authentication_classes`, now it appears on Logout API and gives an error ```{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}```

I have updated my question and added the code of my `CustomEmailBackend` under the `LogoutAPI`, please have a look at that as well.

Comment: @NehaAK this means that the user has not associated an authentication token. Clears the cache of your browser (erase the data), then login again and try the logout. Try also to reload the page before log out

Comment: actually I have made the custom Model Backend, because I wanted the user to login using email instead of username, because default `User` model lets us log in only using username. SO this is why I defined the custom model backend and it is working fine on `LoginAPI`, but after adding `permission_classes` and `authentication_classes` in `LogoutAPI`, it gives the error `'CustomEmailBackend' object has no attribute 'authenticate_header'`

Comment: The backend must not be added under authentication_classes, leaves only permission_classes

Comment: I cleared cache and cookies, but still getting ```{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}``` without `authentication_classes`.

Comment: Import this: `from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication`, then set: `authentication_classes=[TokenAuthentication]`

Comment: OK @RedWheelbarrow , let me do that. Also I tried to print the `request.user` before `request.user.auh_token.delete()` and in the console I got `Unauthorized: /logout` printed

Comment: added `authentication_classes=[TokenAuthentication]`, still same error Authentication credentials were not provided, cleared the cookies and cache again, still getting the same error.

Comment: @NehaAK Probably you should redesign your views. Since you are writing an API, you should not redirect the request, but simply return the token, then the client must set the request header: `Token token_value`. In views that requires authentication use `TokenAuthentication` in `authentication_classes`. If you leave the current code, you must ensures that your client pass the token in header, right no you don't even return the token...

Comment: @NehaAK take a look at this repository to check the code https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth/tree/master/dj_rest_auth

Comment: if I don't redirect, then how do I go to the html page after logging in the user? Also can you tell me how do I set the request header? Sorry if this sounds dumb, I am new to DRF.

Comment: @NehaAK You should not use templates, why you use DRF? If you are creating a website with the frontend/backend in the same place, use Django alone (DRF is useful with a separate React server or an application). To use the token, you must save it in the frontend caches, then when you send a request, pass it in the headers. If you are building a website, I advice you to simply use Django with the default session authentication

Comment: yes I am building a website, and thanks for the suggestion. If I will use simple Django, will I have to use serializers or not?

Comment: @NehaAK With Django alone you only use models, views, forms and templates. Read the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/ documentation about authentication. Login/logout views comes auth of the box. Read this useful tutorial about that https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-login-and-logout-tutorial

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @RedWheelbarrow Should I mark your answer as Solution and close this thread or leave it as it is?

Comment: @NehaAK No problem for the help, I hope you solve the problem. If you can implement the logout in the new way if you want mark the answer as a solution, otherwise leave it as is